# What's the fastest way to send a post request with python?

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

I tried the normal "requests" module but it's really slow, is there any faster way of sending a POST request?

```
import requests 
from time import time 
t = time() 
requests.post("https://httpbin.org/post") 
print(time() - t)  # 0.884 s
```

It is also true with GET requests:

```
requests.get("https://example.com/") 
print(time() - t)  # 0.604 s
```

Comment: you can look at `requests`: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

Comment: Please be more precise @EdwardElric: what is slow? (this is very unprecise, many factors can be involved: your network speed, etc.). Also please include a minimal reproducible code so that we can experiment and see what can be improved with your code.

Comment: I already tried "requests" its super slow.

Comment: import requests
from time import time

t = time()
requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post")
print(t - time())

Comment: No it's not slow, I use it for projects involving thousands of requests and it's not "slow". It's probably *your code* which is non optimal. Please edit your question and include code in your original question (inside a code block) so that we can have a look at what can be improved.

Comment: Slow in comparison to what? Please include your timing benchmark, and to what you compared?

Comment: it takes 0.884, anyway to make it faster.

Comment: Please include all these details in the question. Also 0.1s means starting the python interpreter, doing the request, etc. so it's not slow *per se*. If you need to do many requests, use multithreading. Something like `import threading; threading.Thread(target=f).start()`; you can find other answers here about requests + threading.

Comment: I need to reach the server faster. (request itself not the amount of requests, Im not trying to send multiple requests but only one per 25 seconds and I need it to reach the website faster)

Comment: Sounds like you need a faster internet.

Comment: Down to the ms? At the speed of light, you can only travel 300km in 1 ms :)  It seems you need new laws of physics if your data packet needs to travel 10'000 kms in a few ms :)

Comment: the internet is fast and next to the server im sending the request to. (VPS)

Comment: Isnt there any module a bit faster than requests.post?

Comment: @EdwardElric I edited your question to make it more precise. I voted to reopen.

Comment: @EdwardElric Interesting fact: `requests.get("http://example.com/")` was two times faster than `requests.get("https://example.com/")` for me (HTTP vs HTTPS)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the appropriately named [faster-than-requests](https://github.com/juancarlospaco/faster-than-requests) library:

`pip install faster_than_requests`

Usage:

```
import faster_than_requests as requests

requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post')
```

They provide the following comparison info:

| Library | Speed | Files | LOC | Dependencies | Developers | WebSockets | Multi-Threaded Web Scraper Built-in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PyWGET | `152.39` | 1 | 338 | Wget | >17 | ❌ | ❌ |
| Requests | `15.58` | >20 | 2558 | >=7 | >527 | ❌ | ❌ |
| Requests (cached object) | `5.50` | >20 | 2558 | >=7 | >527 | ❌ | ❌ |
| Urllib | `4.00` | ??? | 1200 | 0 (std lib) | ??? | ❌ | ❌ |
| Urllib3 | `3.55` | >40 | 5242 | 0 (No SSL), >=5 (SSL) | >188 | ❌ | ❌ |
| PyCurl | `0.75` | >15 | 5932 | Curl, LibCurl | >50 | ❌ | ❌ |
| PyCurl (no SSL) | `0.68` | >15 | 5932 | Curl, LibCurl | >50 | ❌ | ❌ |
| Faster_than_requests | `0.40` | 1 | 999 | 0 | 1 | ✅ | ✅ 7, [One-Liner](https://github.com/juancarlospaco/faster-than-requests/blob/master/examples/multithread_web_scraper.py#L2) |

- Lines Of Code counted using [CLOC](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc).
- Direct dependencies of the package when ready to run.
- Benchmarks run on Docker from Dockerfile on this repo.
- Developers counted from the Contributors list of Git.
- Speed is IRL time to complete 10000 HTTP local requests.
- Stats as of year 2020.
- x86_64 64Bit AMD, SSD, Arch Linux.

Despite the project's README saying otherwise, I did have to install Nim (to get `nimble`) before this library would work for me.

---

Alternatively, if that isn't working for you, you can still get almost as good performance with [PycURL](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/).

`pip install pycurl`

Unfortunately it has a rather complex API, as it is just a thin wrapper around libcurl. Here's a basic example:

```
from io import BytesIO

import pycurl


buffer = BytesIO()

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://pycurl.io/')
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
c.getinfo(pycurl.RESPONSE_CODE) # ensure this equals 200, or otherwise handle it
c.close()

buffer.seek(0)
buffer.read() # the response text as bytes
```

For more complex examples, and more information about how to use the API, please refer to [the docs](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html).

---

Next up in the order of decreasing performance, if you're looking for a nicer API, urllib3 may be of interest to you:

`pip install urllib3`

Not to be confused with the builtin library urllib (see below). Interestingly enough, urllib3 is the backend of Requests.

Usage:

```
import urllib3


http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post')
response.status # ensure this equals 200, or otherwise handle it
response.data # the response text as bytes
```

---

For completeness' sake I should also mention that [`urllib.requests`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) is an option.

Usage:

```
import urllib.request


request = urllib.request.Request('https://httpbin.org/post', method='POST')

with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
    response.status # ensure this equals 200, or otherwise handle it
    response.read() # the response text as bytes
```

Comment: faster than pycurl? that's impressive!

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thanks!
Are you able to get `faster_than_requests` to work on macOS?
I'm bumping into https://github.com/juancarlospaco/faster-than-requests/issues/156

Comment: @Pi I was not able to get it working on macOS, but that is because I do not have anything running macOS. I was able to get it working on Linux, but it took a bit of troubleshooting.

Comment: I fixed macOS https://github.com/juancarlospaco/faster-than-requests/issues/156

Answer (score 1):

(i still cant comment) i would recommend to use urllib3

```
from time import time
import urllib3

t = time()
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
http.request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/robots.txt')
print(time() - t)  # 0.383

http.request('POST', 'https://httpbin.org/post')
print(time() - t)  # 0.622
```